How can both ECS services, using the same Docker image but running in different containers, share the same Docker volume?
I'm working on a Django application where I need to upload a file received from a Django admin form to an S3 bucket asynchronously using a Celery shared task. Here is the relevant code:
Django Model:
import os
import uuid
from django.db import models

def generate_file_upload_path(instance: "MyModel", filename: str):
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    randomised_hex = uuid.uuid4().hex
    # name format: meta_uuid-randomised_hex.mp4
    return f"{instance.id}-{randomised_hex}{ext}"

class MyModel(models.Model):
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_file_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail_file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_file_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)

Model Admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from .tasks import process_media_file

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["release_year", "created_by"]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if obj.media_file and obj.thumbnail_file:
            process_media_file.delay(
                {
                    "media_meta_id": str(obj.id),
                    "operation": "upload",
                }
            )

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)

I tried several solutions to make this work:
1. Base64 Encoding:
I saved the base64 encoded string of the media and thumbnail files in the media_url and thumbnail_url fields respectively. In the Celery task, I decoded these strings, created files, and then uploaded them to S3. This approach was slow for larger files.
2. Direct S3 Upload:
I saved the file received from the form directly to the S3 bucket using models.FileField(upload_to="path-to-bucket-dir"). This improved the speed but was not an asynchronous operation.
3. Shared Volume in Docker:
I created a shared volume with the directory /shared and updated the mount points in the ECS task definitions for both the Celery and backend services:
mountPoints
 [
  {
    "containerPath": "/shared",
    "sourceVolume": "shared-volume",
    "readOnly": false
  }
]

volumes
[
  {
    "name": "shared-volume"
  }
]

Tested saving the file in /shared, but the Celery task failed to find the file in /shared during execution.
Current ECS Task Definition Example (This is for rest-prod, and similar configuration is for celery also):
{
  "family": "rest-prod-task",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "rest-container",
      "image": "docker-image-url",
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/shared",
          "sourceVolume": "shared-volume",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ],
      ...
    },
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "shared-volume"
    }
  ]
}

Can someone help me with a solution where I can save files into a shared volume that both the Celery and rest-prod services can access?
I am just learning now, so I am not considering any cloud-native solutions like EFS.

Are these two containers in the same ECS task? or running as two separate tasks?

Celery and Backend service are running in 2 different ECS tasks.

If you're running those as separate ECS tasks you should probably be using an EFS volume instead of a host one.

Not exactly what you asked but could you considere uploading it to S3 from your django app ? Python allows a few way to execute tasks asynchronously.

You can't share ephemeral docker volumes among separate ECS tasks. They would have to be two containers within the same task.

I tried uploading the files to s3 in save_model() method in ModelAdmin, but that was't asyncronous, hence I was intereseted to understand some more solutions.
